# An entire language subdirectory is "duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical" in Google Search Console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, canonical-url

I am currently facing a major issues as the German content of our website at `/de/` is not being indexed.

Here is the error from Google Search Console:

> Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical

one of the URL getting this error is the following: `https://www.example.com/de/` but basically all pages at `/de/` are getting the same error.

To give more insight about the report on URL inspection:

Crawl

- Last crawl `6 Dec 2021, 17:02:09`
- Crawled as `Googlebot smartphone`
- Crawl allowed? `Yes`
- Page fetch `Successful`
- Indexing allowed?  `Yes`
- User-declared canonical : `https://www.example.com/`
- Google-selected canonical : `Same as user-declared canonical`

Here is how the setup is, after all my research, this should be the way to go:

```
<link data-react-helmet="true" rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/de/">
<link data-react-helmet="true" rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="en">
<link data-react-helmet="true" rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/de/" hreflang="de">
```

note: we have removed the `x-default` to test if that would change something for some reason, it hasn't and we will add it back.